# Cross-domain ajax request with setRequestHeader()

Tags: jquery, header

There's my pproblem : I'm trying to do a Basic Authent to another server I trust in, but when I try to change the header of my request, nothing happens.
I used setBeforeSend() method like this :

```
$.ajax ( {
            type: "GET",
            url : currentURL,
            crossDomain : true,
            beforeSend : function (request) {
              console.log(auth + " " + currentUsername + " " + currentPassword);
              request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth); },
            dataType: "xml",
            // user: currentUsername,
            // password : currentPassword,
            success: function (xml) { ...
```

As you can see I also tried to user/password options, but it doesn't work either. I thought it was a problem of Same Origin Policy, but we previously resolved this problem with that :

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
```

When I send my request, I find an 401 error.

Can you help me ?

Thanks ^^ !

Comment: Stupid question but Are you sending the user and password with the request? I see in the sample code you have them commented out. 401 is unauthorized - ie, invalid username and/or password.

Comment: Indeed all that is needed is in the parameter auth associated with the header Authorization, if a add the header with Modify Headers, everything's fine, the only problem is that this header just refuse to appear.